# Delete an object from an Elasticsearch response array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete and object from my Elasticsearch result query, but this object persist whatever I do:

Here is my code :

```
exports.searchUserByKeyWord = (req, res) => {
    User.search(byKeyWordQuery(req), geoDistance(), (err, users) => {
        if (err) requestError(res, err)
            let result = []
            for(let user of users.hits.hits) {
                delete user.address.full
                result.push(user)
            }
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, result)
    })
}
```

Like you can see I'm using delete but it doesn't work, what I can't understand here is the fact that when I replace `sendJsonResponse(res, 200, result)` with 
`sendJsonResponse(res, 200, result[0].address.full)` I found out that this address got successfully deleted, but when I test my API with Postman without adding `result[0].address.full` the address full field is still there ...

Comment: yes, and when I remove the delete I can see it again!!!

Comment: result of the console.log undefined for all users ...

Comment: and when I console.log(user) I see the address.full !!!!!!!!!!!!! i'm going crazy ...

Comment: Can you post the result what you got from elasticsearch??

Answer (score 1):

are you reindexing your elasticsearch data after you delete? the indexed record may persist even though you have removed the document from disk

more on this can be read @
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html